# How to store a specific result of where.exe in a variable for multiple results

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Inside a Batch-script I need to find the location (path) of a specific executable. I use where.exe for that and it works like a charm.

```
@ECHO OFF
:: save the result of the command 'where.exe epstopdf' into the variable progpath
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where.exe epstopdf') do @set progpath="%%a"
:: echo result
echo %progpath%
```

Now I have the problem, that I installed [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) because I want to use the tool *convert*. My problem is, that executing `where.exe convert` returns two results

```
C:\Program Files\ImageMagick\ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16\convert.exe
C:\Windows\System32\convert.exe
```

Unfortunately, when I change the script to

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where.exe convert') do @set progpath="%%a"
echo %progpath%
```

the last result `C:\Windows\System32\convert.exe` is stored in the variable `progpath`.

How can I get the script to save a specific result in the variable (here the first)? Is it possible to stop the for-loop at the line break or something like that?

PS: I miss working on a Linux system

Comment: How do you define "specific result"? How to decide, which result? Always "first"?

Comment: In my current use case I need to find the first result. But I did not want to restrict the question so much, since me in the future, or other users, could be interested specifically in the third or 12th result. Thus, specific means a certain result number. If this is not possible, I would be very happy about a solution for the first result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I need the n-th" is problematic. Better filter to your needs.

Examples: You know, that you are searching explicite for `imageMagick`:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where.exe convert^|find "ImageMagick"') do @set progpath="%%a"
```

or you know, you don't want to get the windows-built-in command, but search for any additional command:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where.exe convert^|find /v "System32"') do @set progpath="%%a"
```

Comment: Thanks, both work great. I use the latter one right now.

Answer (score 0):

`Goto` may "break" your for loop

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where.exe convert') do @set progpath="%%a"&goto break
:break
echo/%progpath%
```

Comment: Thanks @Rafael, that does the trick for the first result. I'd like to give you reputation, but I can't since I don't have enough :(

Answer (score -1):

Remember you can do multiple lines for the action of a `for` statement.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where.exe convert') do (
    if /i not "%%a"=="C:\Windows\System32\convert.exe" set progpath="%%a"
)
```

> PS: I miss working on a Linux system

Two words: Learn PowerShell.  Don't waste your time with batch unless you have no choice.